# How to run heroku restart from inside of a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I understand that from the console I can run `heroku restart`. What I'd like to do is to have a button in my app (admin console), where pushing that button runs a `heroku restart`. Does anyone know how to do that and if it's possible? So the code would look something like this:

```
<button id="heroku_restart">Restart</button>

$("#heroku_restart").click(function() {
    $.post('/restart', {}).done(function(response) {
        alert(response)
    })
})

class AdminsController

    # this is the action mapped to the route /restart
    def restart 
        # code for heroku restart
    end
end
```

Comment: Before you could run `heroku restart` (or any other heroku command), you would need to authenticate your client with `heroku login`. I think it would be impossible to do it inside rails.

Comment: Ooops, I think its possible, using heroku api https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-restart

Comment: Also, they have a gem for the api https://github.com/heroku/platform-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So per @vpibano, as of this writing, doing it with the `platform-api` is a breeze. Here's the action POSTed to by a button on my website:

```
def restart
    heroku = PlatformAPI.connect_oauth(ENV["heroku_oauth_token"]) 
    heroku.dyno.restart_all("lastmingear")
    render nothing: true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the description mentioned in the post, the one way of doing it is :

> 1) First locate the server.pid file

```
pid_file = Rails.root.join("tmp", "pids", "server.opid")
```

> 2) Now, truncate the contents of the file

```
File.open(pid_file, "w") {|f| f.truncate(0)}
```

> 3) Finally, run the server using Kernel module:

```
Kernel.exec("rails s")
```

Note: As rightly, mentioned by @vpibano you will need authentication to access your app.

This is not a working model but a way to achieve the requirement.

Hope it helps!!